# После интеграции backpack нет команды для создания CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, backpack

Всем привет. Решил автоматизировать создание админки в Laravel и нашёл крутой инструмент Backpack. Врод всё ок, разобрался со стилями и решил вот создать CRUD с помощью команды backpack:crud (самая первая инструкция)

Но проблема в том, что этой команды у меня нет. И проблему подобную нагуглить не могу. Есть разные команды, но вот именно эта не попала в лару

Буду благодарен помощи или совету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установку через backpack:install сделали?

Comment: Да, установка прошла успешно, вроде как

Comment: А версия backpack'а какая?

Comment: backpack/crud: 5.6.1

Comment: ### LARAVEL VERSION:
v10.8.0

Comment: Не актуально. Отказываюсь от этой админки. Слишком много нюансов + не устраивают условия для коммерческого испоользования

Comment: backpack удобная штука, если уметь использовать. Есть графический механизм для создания crud-ов. Я обычно руками создаю. Про команду backpack:crud первый раз слышу.

Comment: Backpack очень ужасен на моменте кастомизации. Я бы рекомендовал глянуть Filament или Nova (вторая, правда, платная)